# How to use cache with scriban when reading from a files

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, scriban

I am currently working with .NET Core to render an HTML template from a file. How do use [ITemplateLoader](https://github.com/scriban/scriban/blob/master/doc/runtime.md#include-and-itemplateloader) or CachedTemplates ? There are no full example of the implementation. Currently, I am using memory cache to load file to memory and process it like this:

```
    private async Task<string> GetTemplates()
    {
        string fileName = "email-template.html";
        return await _memoryCache.GetOrCreateAsync<string>("Templates", async f =>
        {
            f.AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
            return await File.ReadAllTextAsync($".\\templates\\{fileName}");
        }) ?? throw new FileNotFoundException(fileName);
    }

    private async Task<string> ApplyTemplateAsync(SomeModel model)
    {
        var templateContent = await GetTemplates();

        var template = Template.Parse(templateContent);
        return template.Render(model);
    }
```